# What is over incrementing pointer show? c++

Tags: c++, pointers, increment

So i've been practicing constructors and deconstructors in classes. And i've referenced a `void` pointer to the class, converted it to `int*` and incremented it like 15 times ( class has size of 1 ). This is what i've got.

PS. forgot to mention that i've decremented the original pointer 15 times in this example.

```
 created instance with value : 3
1

0x28ff1b
01101111
01101111
01101111
00000000
01101111
00000000
01101111
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
01110101
01011000
deleted instance
```

So the question i have is : What am i reading here ?

My basic presumption is PE of cpp code, at starting location of class variable. But i am not sure, i've opened PE in hex editor and i couldn't find the series of '4f-4f-4f-00' anywhere. I am working on Lenovo Laptop with win 7 OS, and c++11.

Comment: What you are reading is "undefined behavior".

Comment: undefined behaviour ? i am not programmer by trade, could you explain it a bit more, or at least tell me keywords so i can google it?

Comment: So in basic terms it is a gibberish that are remains of some other return. Does this means that if i were to write to those memory addresses there would be a valid change to the memory ?

Comment: In basic terms it is gibberish. Full stop. Nothing more can be authoritatively stated. Writing to those memory addresses can have any of the following results: 1) Nothing, 2) The program crashing, 3) The entire computer catching fire and its table collapsing 4) Anything else that can possibly happen. Even reading those memory addresses could do any of the above. You're already in undefined behavior territory, by dereferencing an invalid pointer in the first place, to get the meaningless hex dump.

Comment: Please read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: is this tied in some manner to stack overflow ? I think i've seen some computerphile video that they have explained this by overwriting some bytes in some stack.

Comment: A stack overflow occurs when the program uses more stack memory than is available. What you have sounds like a dodgy-but-legal cast to `void *` followed by another cast that violated the Strict Aliasing Rule by treating a pointer to something that wasn't an `int` as an `int *`. This is followed by reading outside the bounds of a variable, something that I don't think has a formal name. If you ALSO have a stack overflow at this point, meh. Why not? Things can't get much worse, but there are no signs from your description that a stack overflow has occurred. Or that stack is involved at all.

Answer (score 0):

As kindly told by @Sam Varshavchik and [referenced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) by @Jesper Juhl, this is an example of undefined behavior.

Those users (and @user4581301) mentioned that what code produced was [`undefined behaviour`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which results in gibberish. Main issue here is recasting from `void*` to integer type, and then moving outside of scope of the variable to the unknown.

Doing so , and manipulating memory gotten this way can do one (or more) of the following:

- Nothing
- The program crashing
- The entire computer catching fire and its table collapsing
- Anything else that can possibly happen

**Of course I would never recommend anyone to test this code on their own machine due to 2/4 probability of worst case scenario.**